# naming convention with Laravel with double morph relations

Tags: laravel, polymorphic-associations

What is a right naming convention in Laravels when you have 2 morph relations on 1 table (model)?

Example:

```
posts
    id - integer
    title - string
    body - text

videos
    id - integer
    title - string
    url - string

buyers
    id - integer
    name - string

sellers
    id - integer
    name - string

comments
    id - integer
    body - text
    commentable1_id - integer // link to video/posts
    commentable1_type - string // type link to video/posts
    commentable2_id - integer // link to buyers/sellers
    commentable2_type - string // type link to buyers/sellers
```

Now I am using the namme `commentable1` and `commentable2` , but that is not a very good Laravel way. How can I do this in the right Laravel way?

Comment: The best convention imho is one that makes sense and you (and importantly others) can understand with ease, especially after a couple of months away from the code. What is wrong with (assuming it makes sense in your context)  `content_comment` for videos/post and `trader_comment` for buyer/seller

Comment: Did you got the answer you were searching for, if yes, it will be good if you will post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It will be more about personal preference I guess, if I will be doing, I will do it like

```
commentable1_id would be video_post_id
commentable1_type would be video_post_type
commentable2_id would be buyer_seller_id
commentable2_type would be buyer_seller_type
```

And that can be different for another person, but for me, it is self explainable, so I would be using this. Considering you will keep your main model names constant, if you will change that it will change accordingly.

If you want to match laravel standard.

for example your video(s) belongs to post(s), the columns name will be simply `videoable_type`and respectively other two columns will be  `videoable_id`, `sellerable_id` and `sellerable_type`.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)

Comment: Yes I know it is a perrsonal preference and now I am using commentable1 and commentable2 as name, but it is not a very beautiful solution...

Comment: @angelique000 updated my answer with Laravel standard.

Comment: I am afraid sellerable and videoable names are not the Laravel way. Laravel always use the model name with "-able" behind the model name. But my problem is: I have 2 morph relations on 1 model.

Comment: @angelique000 what is the problem with two morph relationfo both you should use {ModelName}able simple, no where it is mentioned if you have multiple morph relation, you will use a different naming standard, you will follow the same,simple.